# Raw PHP in PHPUnit test response

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, phpunit, phing

I've managed to get PHPUnit setup with my Zend Framework project using Phing to execute the tests at build time via an Eclipse external tool. My tests are found and executed at build time, but for some reason, the PHP in the pages is not being interpreted.

In an effort to figure out why my assertions were failing, I added: `echo $this->response->outputBody();` to my test and realized it was echoing raw PHP. If I add `echo get_class($this->response);` I get Zend_Controller_Response_HttpTestCase as the class name, which from what I gather is correct.

I've had this issue with Apache where the file handlers were not setup to send the PHP code through the PHP executable, but as far as I know, this shouldn't be an issue as Phing/PHPUnit should handle executing everything via the executable directly. I don't yet know enough about how PHPUnit or Phing works to know what I could be doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Here's my test class:

```
<?php

class SearchControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testSearchPizzaChicago()
    {
        $this->_search('restaurants', 'chicago, il');
    }


    private function _search($what, $where)
    {
        $this->request->setMethod('POST');

        $this->request->setPost(
                        array(
                            'search_what' => $what,
                            'search_where' => $where,
                        )
        );

        $this->dispatch(Zend_Registry::get('base_url') . '/search/results');

        echo $this->response->outputBody();

        //echo get_class($this->response);

        $this->assertQuery('#results');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        /* Tear Down Routine */
    }


}
```

Here's my console output when I run one of the tests:

```
Buildfile: C:\workspace\myproject\build.xml

myproject > test:

... raw PHP code here ...

  [phpunit] Testsuite: SearchControllerTest
  [phpunit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Incomplete: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.25874 s
  [phpunit] testSearchPizzaChicago FAILED
  [phpunit] Failed asserting node DENOTED BY #results EXISTS
  [phpunit] C:\workspace\frameworks\ZendFramework-1.11\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Constraint\DomQuery.php:263
  [phpunit] C:\workspace\frameworks\ZendFramework-1.11\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php:300
  [phpunit] C:\workspace\myproject\tests\application\controllers\SearchControllerTest.php:34
  [phpunit] C:\workspace\myproject\tests\application\controllers\SearchControllerTest.php:13
  [phpunit] C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phing.php:37

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 2.0895 seconds
```

Comment: Are you using short tags (<? ?> or <?= ?>) in that raw code that's being output? If your server isn't set for php short tags it won't process them as PHP and you'll get an issue similar to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a POST request - if your webserver is operating correctly it would NEVER serve up raw PHP code. Check that `/search/results` script to see if it's being actually executed. Since you're getting php code, most likely it's NOT being seen/treated as a php script and its contents are being served up as plain text instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Part of the problem is that it doesn't go through the webserver, so it wasn't showing up in my logs. Turns out I had errors turned off and the raw PHP was a result of a bug in the code that I didn't find until I turned errors on. Tests are working now.